# How to create yum proxy repository with nexus OSS complete example

Tags: nexus, yum

I have some question:

How to write the url of remote repository while creating proxy repository in nexus OSS.What is the value of $releasever and $basearch
- http://path/to/repo/releases/$releasever/server/$basearch/os/

Comment: `$releasever` and `$basearch` are variables that yum fills in from its configuration. `$releasever` is something like `5` or `6`, etc. for RHEL/CentOS versions and `$basearch` is `i386`, `x86_64`, etc.

Comment: You're question is not clear. What do you exactly want?

Answer (score 0):

There is a `nexus` alternative and more lightweight, named [Repocache](https://github.com/pedia/repocache).